# VS Code debug launch CMake, wrong target

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, cmake

I have a peculiar problem when I try to launch a debug session in VS Code. An old CMake project name gets prepended to the `make` target. Launch command from terminal:

```
[main] Building folder: micro_ros_raspberrypi_pico_sdk pico_micro_ros_example, basic_uart
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: /usr/bin/cmake --build /home/USER/src/micro_ros_raspberrypi_pico_sdk/build --config Debug --target pico_micro_ros_example basic_uart -j 10 --
```

I'm using CMake Tools extension, project is mainly C. Before I started dividing examples into subfolders, and changing project name, everything was working just fine.

Note 1: the old CMake project name was `pico_micro_ros_example`. I changed it to `pico_examples`. There are no references to the old project name in the whole project, I have searched.

Note 2: Doing `CMake debug...` and `make` in the build folder manually works fine.

Note 3: Running

```
/usr/bin/cmake --build /home/tor/src/micro_ros_raspberrypi_pico_sdk/build --config Debug --target basic_subscriber_uart -j 10 --
```

works. That is the `make` command from pressing F5, minus the old project name in target.

Note 4: Restarting PC, VS Code, reinstall CMake Tools, etc. has been attempted.

My `launch.json`:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "Pico Debug",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "executable": "${command:cmake.launchTargetPath}",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "cortex-debug",
            "servertype": "openocd",
            "openOCDLaunchCommands": ["adapter speed 5000"],
            "gdbPath" : "gdb-multiarch",
            "device": "RP2040",
            "showDevDebugOutput": "raw",
            "configFiles": [
                "interface/cmsis-dap.cfg",
                "target/rp2040.cfg"
            ],
            "svdFile": "${env:PICO_SDK_PATH}/src/rp2040/hardware_regs/rp2040.svd",
            "runToEntryPoint": "main",
            "postRestartCommands": [
                "break main",
                "continue"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

CMakeLists.txt in root folder:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

include($ENV{PICO_SDK_PATH}/external/pico_sdk_import.cmake)

project(pico_example C CXX ASM)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

pico_sdk_init()

link_directories(libmicroros)

add_subdirectory(examples)

SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections")

add_compile_options(-Wall
        -Wno-format          # int != int32_t as far as the compiler is concerned because gcc has int32_t as long int
        -Wno-unused-function # we have some for the docs that aren't called
        )
if (CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "GNU")
    add_compile_options(-Wno-maybe-uninitialized)
endif()
```

CMakeLists.txt in example subsub folder (dropping the subfolder CMakeLists.txt):

```
add_executable(basic_subscriber_uart
    basic_subscriber_uart.c
    uart_transport.c
)
target_link_libraries(basic_subscriber_uart
    pico_stdlib
    hardware_uart
    microros
)

target_include_directories(basic_subscriber_uart PUBLIC
    ../../../libmicroros/include
    ../../../include
)

# Configure Pico
pico_enable_stdio_usb(basic_subscriber_uart 0)
pico_enable_stdio_uart(basic_subscriber_uart 1)
add_compile_definitions(PICO_UART_ENABLE_CRLF_SUPPORT=0)
add_compile_definitions(PICO_STDIO_ENABLE_CRLF_SUPPORT=0)
add_compile_definitions(PICO_STDIO_DEFAULT_CRLF=0)

# Generate UF2
pico_add_extra_outputs(basic_subscriber_uart)
```

My cpp_properties.json:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/include",
                "${workspaceFolder}/libmicroros/include"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64",
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Comment: For major changes in a top-level `CMakeLists.txt` file I recommend you clean your configuration and build directory. Just remove the whole directory and rerun `cmake` to generate everything again.

Comment: cool thanks. I have deleted `build` directory multiple times, forgot to write sorry. Are there config folders elsewhere?

Comment: cmake --build C:/foo/build/ --target clean is always worth a try. If you want to do it manually, look for hidden folders.

Comment: Then I would say it's either your `tasks.json` or `launch.json` that have not been configured correctly. You could try starting over fresh, with a new empty project, and copy in the *source and header* files, together with the new `CMakeLists.txt` files. Make sure it's the new one first, before attempting to configure and build the first time. Also close all tabs on VSCode, as well as VSCode itself, when you create the new project structure.

Comment: I also suspect some cache issue in VS Code: The CMake log `[main] Building folder: micro_ros_raspberrypi_pico_sdk pico_micro_ros_example, basic_subscriber_uart` implies it tries to build from a non-existing directory. Or perhaps that is the project name before the comma?

Comment: is there no way to "clean the cache" of CMake Tools extension?

Comment: The CMake cache is in its "build" directory. If you have removed the build directory, then you have also removed the CMake cache.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I copied source and header files to new folder, including `.vscode` folder. Pressing F5 gets debugging going as expected.

Comment: also, copying verbatim to new folder, and starting debug session works. Only change required is to delete old build folder.